# How to write to a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, file-writing

I need help trying to convert an ASCII list to a string list, I have already tried this: 
`ciphertext = str[Nintendo65]`

However it keeps outputting this: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: So clearly `Nintendo65` isn't what you think it is, have you looked into that at all?

Comment: What do you think a "String array" is? What's `Nintendo65` before?

Comment: And what does that have to do with writing something to a file?

Comment: The first version of this question did `str(Nintendo65)` and wrote out a repr string for an `_io.TextWrapper`. Then he edited it to doing `str[Nintendo65]` and of course got the "not subscriptable" TypeError. Voting to close until OP figures out what his question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str[x]
```

tries to access the `x`th element of `str` (which fails with the error you saw).

If you want to convert some object to a string, the correct syntax is

```
my_string = str(my_obj)
```

That gives you a string. If you want to convert that to a list containing each character of your string as one element, use

```
char_list = list(my_string)
```